# Log scale for percent declines

Tags: charts

I have a scatter plot with % declines on the vertical axis. Values range from 0% to -100%, but most of the data points are between 0% to -20%. This makes the chart cluttered.

Is there any way to add a log scale effect like shown here: [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr05d.png)